# Combine every two rows of pandas dataframe into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns (x, y and data), I need to combine every two rows and end up with two data columns.
Essentially I need to combine the rows with the same x and y coordinates into one whilst keeping the two data variables separate creating 4 columns (x, y, u and v)

```
Original data example:
x      y      data
-----------------------
1      1      0.2
1      1      0.5
1      2      0.7
1      2      0.2
...

Expected output:
x      y      u      v
----------------------------
1      1      0.2    0.5
1      2      0.7    0.2
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if sorting your dataframe by coordinates is not an issue then you can probably try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    x=[1,1,1,1],
    y=[1,1,2,2],
    data=[0.2,0.5,0.7,0.2]
)).sort_values(by=["x", "y"])

df["label"] = ["u", "v"] * int(len(df)/2)

df = df.pivot(index=["x", "y"], columns="label", values="data").reset_index()

print(df)
```

| x | y | u | v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.2 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.7 | 0.2 |

Answer (score 0):

Group by `x` and `y`, convert the groups to lists, and then create a dataframe from those lists, and append it to the original dataframe:

```
tmp = df.groupby(['x','y'])['data'].apply(list).reset_index()
tmp = pd.concat([x.drop('data', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(x['data'].tolist(), columns=['u', 'v'])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> tmp
   x  y    u    v
0  1  1  0.2  0.5
1  1  2  0.7  0.2
```

Comment: Seems to work but I am working with a very large database and the processing time is almost unusable. Is it possible without converting to and from a list? Thanks